# Whitelist IBM Cloud function location

Tags: function, ibm-cloud

Hi does anyone know what I can use to whitelist IBM Cloud function locations? I wrote a function that makes rest-api calls to a server but the server needs to whitelist incoming requests. Eg. If I select "US South" as the location for my IBM Cloud function, then what ip/domain/hostname etc does that appear as so I can whitelist it?

Thank you.

Comment: All of those values can be faked. Use an API key or authorization token of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to have a look at IBM Cloud's Statica service which allows you to access restricted resources behind firewalls and whitelisted services using a static IP regardless of where your app is running or the number of instances.

https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/statica

Does this help?